# Facebook SDK delegate methods not firing

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, fbsdk

I have a very simple setup:

```
//AppDelegate.swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.main.bounds) //puts a rectange the same size of the screen
        window?.rootViewController = MainController()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible() //make the window and keyboard available for window

        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        return true
    }

    public func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

        return handled
    }

    .....

}



//Main Controller
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class MainController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(SplashController().view)
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(changeView), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }


    func changeView() {
        let authController = Authenticate()
        view.addSubview(authController.view)
    }

}




//View Controller
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FacebookLogin
import FBSDKLoginKit

class Authenticate: UIViewController,FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        loginButton.delegate = self
        loginButton.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(loginButton)
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("DID LOG OUT!!!")
    }


    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
        print("Login Delegate callback")
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        print("successfully logged into facebook")
    }

    func loginButtonWillLogin(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) -> Bool {
        print("WILL LOGIN")
        return true
    }

}
```

Everything appears generally to work fine with the login process (I get the FB prompt, login, am brought back to the app, etc.)

However, the delegates methods NEVER fire.  I never see "DID LOG OUT" or "Login Delegate Callback" or "successfully logged into facebook".

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for help/suggestions.

Comment: Did you handle Facebook sdk configuration in appdelegate ?

Comment: Yeah, I did handle that - included my appDelegate file above as well for reference.

Comment: And also configured info plist file ?

Comment: Yeah, everything configured in plist

Comment: But I note that in openUrl method use app not application and the method of app delegate with application identifier so I think may be that is the wrong try to change openUrl method  to the proper method .

Comment: Just checked, and it looks like the one I have is the correct one.  I see the one with "application" as you mention, but it is deprecated.  I also put a log in that method to ensure it is firing, and it is getting back to this method in AppDelegate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147957/discussion-between-hosny-and-ryan-ogle).